# How can I find out what missions are available in Borderlands?

Tags: borderlands

As I make my way through the main storyline, Claptrap will randomly appear in the top-right and say something like:

> Greetings, Person X has more jobs for you at Place Y.

Or similar to that.

Unfortunately because I mostly play late at night and my room is adjacent to someone else my dad boards out to, I have to have the volume extremely low and I don't hear what person or where I can get the new mission.

Is there a log of what Claptrap says somewhere maybe?

Comment: If borderlands supports subtitles, that may be a useful method to try.  I'm not at home, so I can't check, but [this page](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/942810-borderlands/51878902) implies that there is subtitle support

Comment: Might I also suggest headphones? If you have an issue with sound late at night it wouldn't hurt to pickup some nice headphones. Games are always better with sound.

Comment: @DaveMcClelland You're right, there is a subtitles option, thanks!

Comment: @Emerica. I'd love to wear my Sennheisers while using my TV (they even have a 3m cable so I could) but it doesn't have a headphone jack :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way for you to view a log of what the claptrap says, but he will repeat often (quite annoying I've found).

Generally, there are only a few sources of quests in any given zone, and you can look up all the [available missions in that area](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Mission#Missions_By_Area) on the wiki.  You'll see that most of the missions originate from bounty boards with only a few NPCs handing out some other ones.